# Get workflow history for an item by itemid in sitecore powershell extension - Sitecore 8.1

Tags: powershell-extensions

I need to create a report by **Sitecore Powershell Extension** where I need to include the details of "Workflow Approver" and "Date on which workflow approved".

I have got the list of referring items for Approved Workflow State. While looping through by foreach loop I need the details of workflow attached to each item by which I want to get the User who approved the workflow and Approved Date.

Below is a partial code for the powershell script  :-

```
Foreach($item in $referringItems) { 

    $itemPaths = $item.Paths.FullPath
    if($item.Paths.FullPath.contains('/sitecore/content/my-website'))
    {
        $rendering = $item | Get-Rendering        
        $addInList = New-Object System.Object
        $addInList | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name ID -Value $item.ID
        // Here I want to get the last updated aproved workflow details as mentioned above in description by $item.ID.              
        $listofWorkflowItems += $addInList
    }
}
$listofWorkflowItems | Show-ListView
```

I have searched a lot but could not get any link/powershell command which can guide me to retrieve this information in sitecore powershell extension.

Could anyone provide some guidance on this Whether this is possible or not the way I am thinking to do?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does this command help? https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/common/get-itemworkflowevent

Comment: @MichaelWest Yes this works. I looked into this website but somehow I missed this specific link to get workflow history of an item. Thanks

Comment: Great. There is also a report which comes out of the box called Stale Workflow Items. This may be a good example to follow.

Comment: @MichaelWest I need to create a custom report where other information is also required that's why I have tried this way. Workflow details is a part of my custom report. I'll keep in mind of your suggestion for future. Really appreciate your help.